# Easy way to find DAG outputs

Tags: airflow

I'm new to airflow and wondering if anyone can point me to a way to easily find the output file names generated by a DAG.

Basically, we work with 1000 DAGs all of which have different output files. I know that I can go into the individual DAGs to find the file names, but is there a way to search the file name and find what DAG it belongs to?

Have tried searching in Airflow, seeing if any of the Google Console outputs have matching data in the List Base jobs but can't see anything.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean with output file names?

Comment: @judoole we have csv files that are created when a DAG successfully runs, so all different reports for partners, payments etc.

Comment: If the task itself returns the destination filenames, could something like xcom_pull(dag_id="your-dag", task_ids="csv-generator") work?